# How to zip the folders and its sub-folders in vb.net 2.0?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have folder in the name of Main1. And inside that folders, i have multiple folders. Like

```
Folders1
Folders2
Folders3
Folders4
```

Each folders have their own files. My requirement is to zip "Main1" folder including all the sub-folders and their files.

I dont want to use any third part tools. I'm planning to use namespace System.Compression with Gzip. Please guys advice.

Comment: If you want to do this with .NET 2.0, System.IO.Compression does not provide any method to directly compress a folder. I newer versions you can use the method ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory

Comment: There is nothing like VB.NET 2.0. You should use NET Framework 2.0 instead to be precise.

Comment: One can actually import the `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll` file which will provide the `ZipFile` class. If it works for .NET 2.0 I don't know, but it does for 4.0 and should do for 3.5.

Answer (score 3):

[ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485721(v=vs.110).aspx) can easily do this for you. Just pass it the path of your Day1 folder and it will zip the entire folder to a zip file. You can iterate over all the Day folders using `System.IO.Directory` class.

(Just realized that you want to stick to .NET Fx 2.0. There is no direct way of doing this in that version. You must either use 3rd-party lib, which you don't want to, or do low-level stuff).

### Edit

If you're really inclined towards doing it by hand, here is a crude way:

1. Get the list of all directories (recursive) in your Day directory; call it `DirList`.
2. Get the list of all files (recursive) in your Day directory; call it `FilesList`.
3. Create a `Dictionary(Of String, String)` and store the name of each file in `FilesList` and the BASE64 representation of its contents; name as Key, content as Value.
4. Save the Dictionary to an XML file using .NET's built-in XML serialization.
5. At the very start of the file, inject the contents of `DirList`.
6. Save the file again. (you could do steps 4-6 in a single step too).
7. Read this file as binary and use GZip to compress the entire content.
8. Write it to a zip file.

To uncompress this file:

1. Open the file and use GZip to decompress and get your entire content.
2. Grab the list of directories from the top and create all recursively.
3. Read the remaining section in its entirety and use XML Serialization to create your `Dictionary` object from it.
4. Iterate through the `Dictionary` and create files using the Key part and then inject contents into the files by converting their Value from BASE64 back to binary.

Let me know if you have questions about any of these steps.

### Edit 2

The following code is compiled against .NET 2.0 and will compress and decompress a directory:

```
Public Function ZipDirectory(DirPath As String) As Byte()
    If Not Directory.Exists(DirPath) Then Return Nothing

    Dim Directories = Directory.GetDirectories(DirPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Dim Files = Directory.GetFiles(DirPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    Dim X As New XmlDocument
    Dim RootNode = X.CreateElement("Content")
    Dim DirsNode = X.CreateElement("Directories")
    Dim FilesNode = X.CreateElement("Directories")

    X.AppendChild(RootNode)
    RootNode.AppendChild(DirsNode)
    RootNode.AppendChild(FilesNode)

    For Each d In Directories
      Dim DirNode = X.CreateElement("Directory")
      Dim PathAttrib = X.CreateAttribute("Path")
      PathAttrib.Value = d.Replace(DirPath & "\", "") 'Create relative paths
      DirNode.Attributes.Append(PathAttrib)
      DirsNode.AppendChild(DirNode)
    Next

    For Each f In Files
      Dim FileNode = X.CreateElement("File")
      Dim PathAttrib = X.CreateAttribute("Path")
      PathAttrib.Value = f.Replace(DirPath & "\", "") 'Create relative paths
      FileNode.Attributes.Append(PathAttrib)
      FileNode.InnerText = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(f))
      FilesNode.AppendChild(FileNode)
    Next

    Using Mem As New MemoryStream()
      X.Save(Mem)
      Dim AllContentsAsByteArray = Mem.ToArray()
      Dim CompressedContent = CompressArray(AllContentsAsByteArray)
      Return CompressedContent
    End Using
  End Function

  Public Sub UnzipDirectory(compressed() As Byte, outputPath As String)
    If Not Directory.Exists(outputPath) Then Directory.CreateDirectory(outputPath)

    Dim Uncompressed = DecompressArray(Compressed)

    Dim X As New XmlDocument

    Using Mem As New MemoryStream(Uncompressed)
      X.Load(Mem)

      Dim RootNode = X.FirstChild
      Dim DirsNode = RootNode.FirstChild
      Dim FilesNode = RootNode.FirstChild.NextSibling

      For Each ChildDir In DirsNode.ChildNodes
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(outputPath, DirectCast(ChildDir, XmlNode).Attributes.Item(0).Value))
      Next

      For Each ChildFile In FilesNode.ChildNodes
        Dim FilePath = Path.Combine(outputPath, DirectCast(ChildFile, XmlNode).Attributes.Item(0).Value)
        Dim Content = Convert.FromBase64String(DirectCast(ChildFile, XmlNode).InnerText)
        File.WriteAllBytes(FilePath, Content)
      Next
    End Using
  End Sub

  Private Function CompressArray(ByVal content() As Byte) As Byte()
    Using outFile As New MemoryStream()
      Using Compress As New GZipStream(outFile, CompressionMode.Compress)
        Compress.Write(content, 0, content.Length)
      End Using

      Return outFile.ToArray()
    End Using
  End Function

  Private Function DecompressArray(ByVal content() As Byte) As Byte()
    Using outFile As New MemoryStream()
      Using inFile As New MemoryStream(content)
        Using Compress As New GZipStream(inFile, CompressionMode.Decompress)
          Dim buffer(1023) As Byte
          Dim nRead As Integer
          Do
            nRead = Compress.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            outFile.Write(buffer, 0, nRead)
          Loop While nRead > 0
        End Using
      End Using

      Return outFile.ToArray()
    End Using
  End Function
```

The code should be used like this:

```
'To zip a directory
Dim Compressed = ZipDirectory("C:\SomeDir") 
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\somedir.zip", Compressed)

'To unzip a zipped file
Dim Compressed = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\somedir.zip") 
UnzipDirectory(Compressed, "C:\SomeDir2")
```

Comment: Actually this piece of code will get execute in SSIS script task using VB.NET 2.0 version. I cant use the latest version of VB.NET here. Thats my concern.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is using `System.IO.Compression`

Example from MSDN site:

[Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280(v=vs.80).aspx)

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
imports System.IO
imports System.IO.Compression

Public Class CompressionSnippet

    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim path As String = "test.txt"

        ' Create the text file if it doesn't already exist.
        If Not File.Exists(path) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Creating a new test.txt file")
            Dim text() As String = {"This is a test text file.", _
                "This file will be compressed and written to the disk.", _
                "Once the file is written, it can be decompressed", _
                "imports various compression tools.", _
                "The GZipStream and DeflateStream class use the same", _
                "compression algorithms, the primary difference is that", _
                "the GZipStream class includes a cyclic redundancy check", _
                "that can be useful for detecting data corruption.", _
                "One other side note: both the GZipStream and DeflateStream", _
                "classes operate on streams as opposed to file-based", _
                "compression data is read on a byte-by-byte basis, so it", _
                "is not possible to perform multiple passes to determine the", _
                "best compression method. Already compressed data can actually", _
                "increase in size if compressed with these classes."}

            File.WriteAllLines(path, text)
        End If

        Console.WriteLine("Contents of {0}", path)
        Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(path))

        CompressFile(path)
        Console.WriteLine()

        UncompressFile(path + ".gz")
        Console.WriteLine()

        Console.WriteLine("Contents of {0}", path + ".gz.txt")
        Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(path + ".gz.txt"))

    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub CompressFile(ByVal path As String)
        Dim sourceFile As FileStream = File.OpenRead(path)
        Dim destinationFile As FileStream = File.Create(path + ".gz")

        Dim buffer(sourceFile.Length) As Byte
        sourceFile.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)

        Using output As New GZipStream(destinationFile, _
            CompressionMode.Compress)

            Console.WriteLine("Compressing {0} to {1}.", sourceFile.Name, _
                destinationFile.Name, False)

            output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        End Using

        ' Close the files.
        sourceFile.Close()
        destinationFile.Close()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub UncompressFile(ByVal path As String)
        Dim sourceFile As FileStream = File.OpenRead(path)
        Dim destinationFile As FileStream = File.Create(path + ".txt")

        ' Because the uncompressed size of the file is unknown, 
        ' we are imports an arbitrary buffer size.
        Dim buffer(4096) As Byte
        Dim n As Integer

        Using input As New GZipStream(sourceFile, _
            CompressionMode.Decompress, False)

            Console.WriteLine("Decompressing {0} to {1}.", sourceFile.Name, _
                destinationFile.Name)

            n = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            destinationFile.Write(buffer, 0, n)
        End Using

        ' Close the files.
        sourceFile.Close()
        destinationFile.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Truly you would be better off using [SharpLibZip](http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/)